# How to set child width equal to parent width minus x px by js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to set width of child element according to parent width - x px.
what's wrong in my code :

```
$("#formTable table:first-child").css("width",$("#Content").css("width")-5)
```

where formTable is child of Content.

Comment: Use `$("#Content").width()` instead of `$("#Content").css("width")`

Comment: You can also use the css function `calc`. To make a child 10px narrower than it's parent, you can use: `width: calc(100% - 10px);`. The advantage of this is that the browser will re-calculate the size upon re-size, rather than forcing you to handle an event and re-calculate the width yourself.

Comment: I don't know how, but it's work now without any changes. thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$("#formTable table:first-child").css("width",$("#Content").width()-5)
```